# compare elements of file c#

Tags: c#, file, compare, element

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
apples 158
oranges 9
pumpkins 10
```

I want to find out which one of the fruits has the highest stock.

```
var myfile = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\file.txt");

for (int x = 0; x < myfile.Length; x++)
{
    var csv = myfile[x].Split(' ');
    var fruit = csv(0);
    var occurence = double.Parse(csv[1]);
}
```

Output here should be `apples`.

Is there a shorter way than endless looping and comparing with if statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one statement using `File.ReadLines` and `LINQ`.I used `int.Parse` instead of `double.Parse`, because I thought there cannot be a `2,5` apples in the stock.

```
var maxFruit =  File.ReadLines("path")
                .Select(x => x.Split())
                .OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x[1]))
                .Select(x => x[0])
                .First();
```